# JXTreeTable and JComboBox cell editor

Tags: java, jcombobox, jxtable, jxtreetable

How can I use `JComboBox` as cell editor in [`JXTreeTable`](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html)? Can you give me a working example please?

Answer (score 2):

```
table.getColumn(0).setCellEditor(
    new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox(new Object[]{"A", "B", "C"})));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JComboBox` using cell editor for all column using below code except a column which `JXTreeTable` uses to display hierarchical data.

Ex:

```
    TableColumnExt column = this.tree.getColumnExt(1);
    column.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox());
```

i.e. you can not use `JComboBox` for a column which `JXTreeTable` uses to display hierarchical data.

In `JXTreeTable` java doc they have mention that,

> JXTreeTable is a specialized table consisting of **a single column in which to display hierarchical data**, and any number of other columns in which to display regular data.

JXTreeTable creates `TreeTableCellEditor` internally which is used to display hierarchical data.

[`TreeTableModel`](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/treetable/TreeTableModel.html) provides method [`getHierarchicalColumn()`](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/treetable/TreeTableModel.html#getHierarchicalColumn()) in which you can specify which colum uses to display hierarchical data

Now if you want to provide `JComboBox` at first column(0th position column is by default hierarchical column) then you have to provide different column index using TreeTableModel otherwise you have to shift your column(recommended from my side).

**Code to provide different column for hierarchical data**

```
this.tree = new JXTreeTable(new DefaultTreeTableModel() {
    public int getHierarchicalColumn() {
       return 2;
    }
 });
```

Preview
[image]

NOTE: I have provided this solution such that you can achieve your solution with  minimum customization code. There can be another way but I personally find this solution very easy to implement